Problem when using both doclicense and changes
When I load both doclicense and changes the resulting PDF is incomplete but I get no error message using pdflatex.
Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[type={CC},modifier={by},version={4.0}]{doclicense}
\usepackage[commandnameprefix=ifneeded]{changes}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
This is the introduction.
\added[comment={This is a comment}]{New text}
\highlight{Highlight me}
\comment{comment me}
\section{Can you see this?}
Example text.
\end{document}

The PDF does not show the "Can you see this?" section. When I remove the inclusion of doclicense everything works. Any idea what is going on here?

You get a warning in the log: Package changes Warning: Command comment is already defined, using chcomment on input line 783..  \comment  as defined by the verbatim packages suppresses the following text.  In a current texlive I also get an error that hyperref is loaded to late, and had to load it before doclicense.

You must use the \chcomment command, as comment is defined by the verbatim package (loaded by doclicense):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref} %must be loaded before hyperxmp in newer texlive, see https://github.com/ypid/latex-packages/issues/111
\usepackage[type={CC},modifier={by},version={4.0}]{doclicense}
\usepackage[commandnameprefix=ifneeded]{changes}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
This is the introduction.
\added[comment={This is a comment}]{New text}
\highlight{Highlight me}
\chcomment{comment me}
\section{Can you see this?}
Example text.
\end{document}


